# Java annotation processing: reference generated type in other generated code

Tags: java, annotation-processing, javapoet

```
@GenerateInterface class A {}

@GenerateInterface class B {
  void setA(IA a) {}
}
```

My annotation processor should generate these interfaces:

```
interface IA {}

interface IB {
  void setA(IA a);
}
```

`B` compiles fine with correct import statement. `IB` however, misses the parameter `IA a`. I use [javapoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) to generate the interfaces. Code for compying the method parameters:

```
method.getParameters().forEach(p -> {
  ParameterSpec.Builder parameterBuilder = ParameterSpec.builder(
      TypeName.get(p.asType()),
      p.getSimpleName().toString(),
      p.getModifiers().toArray(new Modifier[p.getModifiers().size()]));
  p.getAnnotationMirrors().stream()
      .map(AnnotationSpec::get)
      .forEach(parameterBuilder::addAnnotation);
  methodBuilder.addParameter(parameterBuilder.build());
});
```

`method` is an `ExecutableElement`. `p.asType()` only holds the simple name `IA`. At this point, `IA` has possibly not been generated yet, so no fully qualified name is available.

At the moment I generate interfaces one by one for each annotated class. As far as I understand I first of all need a list of all annotated classes and their derived interface names. Then when I encounter a parameter that is of a yet to be generated type, get the fully qualified name from the list above to insert a correct import statement.

Is there a smart way to do this? Can I at least distinguish yet to be compiled types from already compiled ones?

Edit: [full code](https://github.com/xinra-nucleus/nucleus-interface-generator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xinra/nucleus/interfacegenerator/InterfaceGenerator.java)

Comment: Have a look at `ErrorType` and round-based compilation. Google's auto-common have a decent implementation, that can serve as example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on an Annotation Processor for my [Kripton Persistence Library](http://github.com/xcesco/kripton) and I have a similar problem. My problem is similar but not the same: in my generated classes I referer other generated classes that are generated in the same round.

The solution that I apply is simply "generate" the TypeName by hand. In my Annotation Processor, I use a specific class, which source you can found [here](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton/blob/master/kripton-processor/src/main/java/com/abubusoft/kripton/processor/core/reflect/TypeUtility.java).

Kripton will generate classes that implement SQLite-based DAO pattern for Android platform. When I generated my DataSource, I need to referer the DAO classes that will be generated in the same round. To do this and avoid the same your problem, I generate the associated TypeName. You can see that on method `buildDataSource` of the class [BindDataSourceBuilder](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton/blob/master/kripton-processor/src/main/java/com/abubusoft/kripton/processor/sqlite/BindDataSourceBuilder.java).

Hope that information is still useful for you.